# Use by = each row for data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table and I am trying to create a new variable that is a function of all the other columns. A simplified example would be if I simply wanted to sum or take an average across all the rows. For example:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:9, b = seq(10,90,10), c = seq(11:19), d = seq(100, 900, 100))
```

I want to create a vector/column that is simply the average of all the columns. The syntax that I think of would look something like this:

```
dt[, average := mean(.SD)]
```

However, this sums the whole thing. I know I can also do:

```
dt[, average := lapply(.SD, mean)]
```

But this gives a single row result. I'm essentially looking for the equivalent of:

```
dt[, average := lapply(.SD, mean), by = all]
```

such that it simply calculates this for all the rows, without having to create an "id" column and doing all of my calculating by that column. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the usual way might be `dt[, m := Reduce(\`+\`, .SD)/length(.SD)]`. If you're doing rowwise operations, though, maybe you should be using a matrix.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following data.table code worked for me.

```
 dt[, average := rowMeans(.SD)]
```

As pointed out by @jangorecki, it is possible to construct your own function to run by row as long as you remember that each row is a list object:

```
# my function, must unlist the argument
myMean <- function(i, ...) mean(unlist(i), ...)
```

using `by=seq_len`

```
dt[, averageNew := myMean(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]
```

using `row.names`

```
dt[, averageOther := myMean(.SD), by = row.names(dt)]
```

Comment: Nice, I'll remember this one. Though, I actually have a custom function that I wanted to use. Is it possible to do something similar in that case? For example:

    dt[, output := myfunction(.SD)]

Comment: With a customized function, you may be best off going with @señor-o s method.

Comment: @lmo with customized function it may be better just to use `dt[, a := f(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]`

Comment: @jangorecki I'm not sure this is always effective: with function `myMean <- function(i) mean(i)`, the line `dt[, average3 := myMean(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]` returns a column of NA.

Comment: try `mean(list(1,2))` to see what is happening in your `myMean`

Comment: @jangorecki aha. Thanks. That aspect very much slipped my mind.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks to jangorecki, I added two lines of code that will process self-rolled functions by row. There is likely a speed hit, so if you are working with datasets with tens of millions of rows, you should take Frank's comment and señor-o s method into account and maybe run some tests.

Answer (score 7):

I think a much better solution is just to use `apply` for this, which was made for row-wise matrix-like operations where as `data.table` was not.

```
> dt$average = apply(dt, 1, mean)
> dt

   a  b c   d average
1: 1 10 1 100      28
2: 2 20 2 200      56
3: 3 30 3 300      84
4: 4 40 4 400     112
5: 5 50 5 500     140
6: 6 60 6 600     168
7: 7 70 7 700     196
8: 8 80 8 800     224
9: 9 90 9 900     252
```