# How to apply a function on every row of a data frame?

Tags: r

I would like to use this package metap
to calculate multiple o values

I have my data frame with 3 p values

```
    > dput(head(tt))
structure(list(RS = c("rs2089177", "rs4360974", "rs6502526", 
"rs8069906", "rs9905280", "rs4313843"), G = c(0.9986, 0.9738, 
0.9744, 0.7184, 0.7205, 0.9804), E = c(0.7153, 0.7838, 0.7839, 
0.4918, 0.4861, 0.8522), B = c(0.604716, 0.430228, 0.42916, 0.521452, 
0.465758, 0.474313)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names  = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10200eee0>)
```

and data frame with corresponding weights for each of the p values
from the tt data frame

```
   > dput(head(df))
structure(list(wg = c(40.6324993078201, 40.6324993078201, 40.6324993078201, 
 40.6324993078201, 40.6324993078201, 40.6324993078201), we = c(35.3977400408557, 
35.3977400408557, 35.3977400408557, 35.3977400408557, 35.3977400408557, 
35.3977400408557), wb = c(580.643608420863, 580.643608420863, 
580.643608420863, 580.643608420863, 580.643608420863, 580.643608420863
), RS = c("rs2089177", "rs4360974", "rs6502526", "rs8069906", 
"rs9905280", "rs4313843")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

RS column is the same in df and tt

How to use this sunz() function to create a new data frame which would
look the same as tt only it would have additional column, say named
"META" which has calculated meta p values for each row

This i s example of how much would be p value in the first row:

```
 > sumz(c(0.9986,0.7153,0.604716), weights = c(40.6325,35.39774,580.6436), na.action = na.fail)
p =  0.6940048
```

this is the function I was referring to:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metap/versions/1.1/topics/sumz

I tried merging those two data frames and applying a function on each row:

```
> head(q)
       ID         P         G       E       wb      wg       we
1:  rs1029830 0.0979931 0.0054060 0.39160 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774
2:  rs1029832 0.1501820 0.0028140 0.39320 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774
3: rs11078374 0.1701250 0.0009805 0.49730 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774
4:  rs1124961 0.1710150 0.7252000 0.05737 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774
5:  rs1135237 0.1493650 0.6851000 0.06354 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774
6: rs11867934 0.0757972 0.0006140 0.00327 580.6436 40.6325 35.39774


helper <- function(x) {
   p <- sumz(x[2:4], weights = x[5:7])$p
   p
}

q$META <- apply(q, MARGIN = 1, helper)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
 Error in sumz(x[2:4], weights = x[5:7]) : 
  Must have at least two valid p values
```

Comment: please provide your sample data by `dput(head(tt))` etc. rather than just the printed output

Comment: I just did. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starts, since you say that `RS` is the same between the two, that to me sounds the caution of *"how certain are we that the rows always line up correctly?"* To be defensive, I'll say "not 100%", and join/merge them together so that they are guaranteed in the right order.

```r
quux <- tt[df, on="RS"]
quux
#           RS      G      E        B      wg       we       wb
# 1: rs2089177 0.9986 0.7153 0.604716 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
# 2: rs4360974 0.9738 0.7838 0.430228 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
# 3: rs6502526 0.9744 0.7839 0.429160 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
# 4: rs8069906 0.7184 0.4918 0.521452 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
# 5: rs9905280 0.7205 0.4861 0.465758 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
# 6: rs4313843 0.9804 0.8522 0.474313 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436
```

From here, it's just applying each portion of the row with the other portion of the same row, for each row:

```r
quux$META <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(quux)), function(rn) {
  unlist(sumz(as.matrix(quux[,.(G,E,B)])[rn,], weights = as.vector(quux[,.(wg,we,wb)])[rn,],
              na.action=na.fail)["p"])
})
quux
#           RS      G      E        B      wg       we       wb      META
# 1: rs2089177 0.9986 0.7153 0.604716 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.9863582
# 2: rs4360974 0.9738 0.7838 0.430228 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.9294546
# 3: rs6502526 0.9744 0.7839 0.429160 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.9300445
# 4: rs8069906 0.7184 0.4918 0.521452 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.6379392
# 5: rs9905280 0.7205 0.4861 0.465758 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.6055061
# 6: rs4313843 0.9804 0.8522 0.474313 40.6325 35.39774 580.6436 0.9605584
```

Or a more `data.table`-centric way:

```r
mysumz <- function(x, w) sumz(unlist(x), weights = unlist(w), na.action = na.fail)[["p"]]
quux[, META := mysumz(.(G,E,B), .(wg,we,wb)), by = seq_len(nrow(quux))]
```

(borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36802640). The secondary function is required because each call to `mysumz` has a `list` for each of `x` and `w`, but `sumz` needs vectors. If you want to verify this, first call `debugonce(mysumz)` then run the `quux[,META:=...]` and check out `x` and `w` ... and how it works.

Comment: Hi please check my example, this solution does not give correct solution sumz(c(0.9986,0.7153,0.604716), weights = c(40.6325,35.39774,580.6436), na.action = na.fail)