# How can I apply a function over each of the rows of a data.table object in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table where I want to apply `t.test` over each row of columns A and B:

```
DT <- data.table(A=rnorm(30,0,1),B=rnorm(30,0,5))
DT[,pval:=t.test(A,B)$p.value]
```

However, the above result gives me the same value in `pval`, how can I do this row-wise?

Comment: I don't think you can do a `t.test` when there are only 2 values in each row.

Comment: Sorry, I actually want to perform a t-test with only two numbers. I had meant to use a different test on proportions but came up with the wrong example.

Comment: Try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802385/use-by-each-row-for-data-table) also!

Comment: A row-wise t-test with two columns will not work, evidenced by testing `t.test(1,2)` and receiving the error `not enough 'x' observations`. It appears that you have two columns of data, where each value is more meaningful than (say) `rnorm(1)`. Perhaps you should reframe your question with a description of the data you have ("ratios" is an important thing when discussing statistical tests) and what significance you are trying to find. Then ... it will likely be migrated to [stats.se], where the pedagogy of *"what statistical test is relevant here"* is perfectly suited.